# How to "Model.create()" on Sequelize without set id automatically

Tags: node.js, database, express, orm, sequelize.js

When I run **Model.create()** sequelize is setting automatically on insertion the field **ID** but

is a relation **one-to-one** where the table do **not have ID** have intead an **driver_id** the is **PK & FK**.

Comment: I don't see `user_id ` in your models

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`this.removeAttribute('id');` on `super.init()` works:

```
class Cars extends Model {
    static init(connection) {
        super.init(
            {
                model: DataTypes.STRING,
  
            },
            {
                sequelize: connection
            }
        );

        this.removeAttribute('id');
    }

    static associate(models) {
        this.belongsTo(models.Owners, { foreignKey: 'driver_id', as: 'driver' });
      }
}

module.exports = Cars;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).